# Filter out repeating words

Tags: python, string, list

This is a program I came through to while revising my Python core area.

```py
input = 'hello world and practice makes perfect and hello world again'
output=[]
filter=''
for word in input.split():
    if word not in filter:
        filter = filter + word
        print(filter)
    else:
        continue
    output.append(filter)
    print(' '.join(output))
```

I'm looking for the following output:

```
hello world and practice makes perfect again
```

But instead, this is what I am getting:

```
hello 
helloworld 
helloworldand 
helloworldandpractice 
helloworldandpracticemakes 
helloworldandpracticemakesperfect 
helloworldandpracticemakesperfectagain
```

How can I get the output I want, what changes I should make, I know I can make it by sort and set functions, but I need to accomplish this without built in functions.

Comment: What is in your `input`?

Comment: Don't print filter at each iteration. Print it once at the end. And append spaces between words

Comment: Why are you concatenating strings? Make a list of unique words, then just join that.

Comment: With your string concatenation method, if a later word is a substring of a previous word, it won't be included in the result. E.g. `hello hell` will just return `hello`.

Comment: Also, try to avoid using Python keywords or function names as variable names (ex: `filter` and 'input').

Comment: Just put the print at the end without INDENT!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

By using `set` data type each term in it is unique, no repeated term is allowed. Also if you cannot use built-in functions it is a bad practice to use variables identifier to shadow other objects, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) you can find a full list of the built-in functions' names (so don't use `input` or `filter` but smt like `intput_str`, `input_`, ...).

Notice further that the statement `filter = filter + word` can be just rewritten using the increment operator `filter += word`

Here a possible solution

```
input_str = 'hello world and practice makes perfect and hello world again'

# "lookup set" keep tracks of all non-repeated terms
cache = set()

res = '' # result
for word in input_str.split():
    # check if words is already met
    if word not in cache:
        # update final result
        res = res + word + ' '

    # update "lookup set"
    cache.add(word)

# remove white space added at the "last" iteration
res = res.rstrip()

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just use a built in data structure that discards duplicates but maintains order of occurrence, like a simple `dict`:

```
sent = 'hello world and practice makes perfect and hello world again'

" ".join(dict.fromkeys(sent.split(), None))
# 'hello world and practice makes perfect again'
```

Comment: I also posted a similar answer ... just deleted it:)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `print` after every iteration over a word which is causing an output of every unique word and outputting it to a new line, instead, unique words should be saved to a list and output after you have finished iterating over the entire list.

```py
def filter_repeating_words(input):
    word_list = input.split()
    filtered_words = []

    for word in word_list:
        if word not in filtered_words: # If this word has not been seen before
            filtered_words.append(word) # Add it to our list

    return " ".join(filtered_words) # Return our list of unique words as a string

input = "hello world and practice makes perfect and hello world again"
print(filter_repeating_words(input)) # "hello world and practice makes perfect again"
```

Using a list to store previously seen words instead of concatenating them to a string allows to reliably determine whether a word is repeating.